# Como puedo redireccionar parametros a otra pagina con react mediante un form?

Tags: reactjs

quiero hacer que al momento de presionar enter, me envié a la otra pagina junto a sus parámetros, por ejemplo tengo un componente llamado buscador, el cual solo es un input (quiero que se envie la info solo presionando enter).
Mi codigo es algo asi:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

export default function Buscador(){

    const [search, setSearch] = useState(String)


    return(

            <form action={`/search?s=${search}`}>
                <input 
                    className="form-control mr-sm-2" 
                    type="search" 
                    placeholder="Buscar" 
                    aria-label="Search" 
                    width='100%'
                    onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)}

                />
            </form>

    )

}
```

la otra pagina es una llamada search que recibe un parámetro en una variable (s) la cual lo recibe perfectamente, pero no logro enviarle el parámetro mediante el formulario en el componente, intente con funciones, con windows.location, con router.push, y con los métodos get y post en el form pero nada de nada, la mayoría me devolvía a la misma pagina desde donde hacia la búsqueda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he solucionado de esta forma para el que tenga la misma duda.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

export default function Buscador(){

    const [search, setSearch] = useState(String)

    let redir = () => {
        window.location.href = `/search?s=${search}`;
    }

    return(

            <form onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault() || redir()}>
                <input 
                    className="form-control mr-sm-2" 
                    type="search" 
                    placeholder="Buscar" 
                    aria-label="Search" 
                    width='100%'
                    onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)}        
                />
            </form>

    )

}
```